# Create an array between two numbers that can only be incremented a set amount of times?

Tags: r

Hopefully the title is clear enough. I'm trying to create an array of numbers between
40.56 and 100.00. But it can only be incremented 25 times. Meaning there needs to perfectly be
25 increments between 40.56 and 100.00.

How can I go about automating this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `seq` with `length.out` argument specifying desired length of the sequence.

```
seq(40.56, 100, length.out = 25)
#[1]  40.6  43.0  45.5  48.0  50.5  52.9  55.4  57.9  60.4
#[10]  62.9  65.3  67.8  70.3  72.8  75.2  77.7  80.2  82.7
#[19]  85.1  87.6  90.1  92.6  95.0  97.5 100.0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help!